# How to display system loading screen in WatchOS2?

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-2

How do WeChat display a system loading screen like this?
When I first launch the app, it's showing me the second image. Not like WeChat.

[image: Wechat]

When I try to do it, it's different. My one is showing time as well. I'd like to hide Title and time from status bar and show title under the activity indicator while initial loading i.e. show a loading screen like WeChat.

[image: My One]

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an API for controlling the visibility of the status bar in WatchKit. So you cannot do that.

[About splash screen:](https://medium.com/@benjones_design/design-for-the-apple-watch-the-sequel-6565b4c07e6a)

> Firstly to the splash screen, no, just no. Splash screens are only
>   just about acceptable on phones and tablets, but the Apple Watch is
>   used in a very different way. The way we look at usage between the
>   Apple Watch and phones and tablets, is that a user will be using the
>   watch for a brief moment, 5–10 seconds and they are out of there! If
>   we put a splash screen on the Apple Watch, users will become
>   frustrated that they have to wait 2 seconds, just to see some quick
>   information. On other devices it’s not so bad as the user’s behaviour
>   is more likely to be relaxed and willing to give a little more time to
>   viewing the app.

Comment: How does WeChat and all other apps do that?

Comment: @moeseth it's system screen while your app is launching you will see this screen

Comment: the second image is what I see when I first launch. I am not seeing system screen like WeChat or any other ones.

Comment: am having the same problem here ,, did you figure it out ?

Comment: @Ghass.64, i think it's the different between watch os 1 and 2.